# web server cannot find .mtl file

Tags: three.js, webserver, http-status-code-404, azure-web-app-service

So, I'm using THREE.js with .obj and .mtl files to display 3D models on a webpage. This has been working fine through the development and runs great on the Brackets' live preview local server. However, once I uploaded the files to a real web server through FTP and try and load the page I get this error in the console:

> http://jacksteel.azurewebsites.net/Models/Aventador/Avent.mtl Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

Double checking through FileZilla the file itself is definitely in the place It's supposed to be.
Unless I'm missing something I see no reason for this not to work, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> http://jacksteel.azurewebsites.net/Models/Aventador/Avent.mtl Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

I could reproduce the issue on my side.

[image]

To resolve the issue, please try to configure the  element to add .mtl MIME type in your Web.config.

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>         
      <remove fileExtension=".mtl" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".mtl" mimeType="text/plain" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'm very new to azure, how to I edit the web.config file on azure?